# Python Pandas Pivot Table

Tags: python, python-2.7, pivot-table, pandas

I am trying to do a pivot table of frequency counts using Pandas.

I have the following code:

```
 from pandas import pivot_table, DataFrame, crosstab
 import numpy as np
 df=DataFrame(
    {'Y':[99999991, 99999992, 99999993, 99999994, 99999995,
          99999996, 99999997, 99999998, 99999999],
     'X':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
     'X2':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})
 print pivot_table(df,rows=['Y'], cols=['X'],aggfunc=np.sum)
```

This is my output:

```
 X          1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
 Y                                         
  99999991   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
  99999992 NaN   2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
  99999993 NaN NaN   3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
  99999994 NaN NaN NaN   4 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
  99999995 NaN NaN NaN NaN   5 NaN NaN NaN NaN
  99999996 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   6 NaN NaN NaN
  99999997 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   7 NaN NaN
  99999998 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   8 NaN
  99999999 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   9
```

This is my desired output:

```
 X          1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
 X2                                         
   1   99999991 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
   2 NaN   99999992 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
   3 NaN NaN   99999993 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
   4 NaN NaN NaN   99999994 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
   5 NaN NaN NaN NaN   99999995 NaN NaN NaN NaN
   6 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   99999996 NaN NaN NaN
   7 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   99999997 NaN NaN
   8 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   99999998 NaN
   9 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   99999999
```

This is what I keep getting:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 9 entries, 1 to 9
Data columns:
('Y', 1L)    1  non-null values
('Y', 2L)    1  non-null values
('Y', 3L)    1  non-null values
('Y', 4L)    1  non-null values
('Y', 5L)    1  non-null values
('Y', 6L)    1  non-null values
('Y', 7L)    1  non-null values
('Y', 8L)    1  non-null values
('Y', 9L)    1  non-null values
dtypes: float64(9)
```

Does anyone know why?  Is the output too big. I can't seem to find anything on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace `rows=['Y']` with `rows=['X2']`

```
>>> print pivot_table(df,rows=['X2'], cols=['X'],aggfunc=np.sum)
      Y                                        
X     1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
X2                                             
1   101  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   NaN  102  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   NaN  NaN  103  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4   NaN  NaN  NaN  104  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  105  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  106  NaN  NaN  NaN
7   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  107  NaN  NaN
8   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  108  NaN
9   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  109
```

Comment: Thank you! I edited the question because I think it is dependent on the numbers and I cannot receive the data in the above format, do you have any idea why?

Comment: That output is expected behavior. Have you read this part of the documentation: http://pandas.sourceforge.net/reshaping.html ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
In [3]: df.pivot_table('Y', rows='X', cols='X2')
X2         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9
X                                                                                           
1   99999991       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2        NaN  99999992       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
3        NaN       NaN  99999993       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
4        NaN       NaN       NaN  99999994       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
5        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  99999995       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
6        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  99999996       NaN       NaN       NaN
7        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  99999997       NaN       NaN
8        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  99999998       NaN
9        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  99999999
```

This would also work:

```
pivot_table(df, 'Y', rows='X', cols='X2')
```

or

```
pivot_table(df, rows='X', cols='X2')['Y']
```